# CefSharp convert html to pdf doesn't work

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, cefsharp

I create a project to convert an html page to pdf, but it returns null. Can anyone help me?

```
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CefSharp.OffScreen;
using System.Threading;
using CefSharp;

namespace CefTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

        [STAThread]
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await HtmlToPdfHeadless();
        }

        private static async Task HtmlToPdfHeadless()
        {
            const string testUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
            var settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(testUrl);
            string path = "Test.pdf";
            Task printToPdfAsync = PrintToPdfAsync(path);
            await printToPdfAsync;
        }

        public static async Task PrintToPdfAsync(string path)
        {
            await browser.PrintToPdfAsync(path);
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I tried leaving the method asynchronous but it still doesn't work.

Comment: CefSharp was a nightmare for me in production when targeting older operating systems. I found `HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp` to work flawless. `Polybioz.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.Core` for .NET Core.

Comment: Have you ever successfully used html to pdf conversion using CefSharp?

Comment: I gave up on CefSharp. Checkout `PuppeteerSharp` `await page.PdfAsync(outputFile);` https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp

Comment: That's the problem.
I already did the conversion but my task asks me to use specifically CefSharp.

Comment: You have to wait for the page to load before you can print to PDF. Start with the example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.OffScreen/Program.cs#L48

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution (without using a SynchronizationContext) might look like the following:

**Note**: Cef.Initialize and Cef.Shutdown must be called on the same Thread. Your example Cef.Shutdown would be called on the Thread Pool and as a result throw an Exception.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CefSharp.OffScreen;

namespace CefSharp.MinimalExample.OffScreen
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);

            HtmlToPdfHeadless().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            // Cef.Initialize and Cef.Shutdown **MUST** be called
            // on the same thread.
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }

        private static async Task HtmlToPdfHeadless()
        {
            const string testUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
            
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(testUrl);

            // Wait for browser to load
            await browser.WaitForInitialLoadAsync();

            // Alternatively wait for the browser to stop rendering 
            await browser.WaitForRenderIdleAsync();

            string path = "Test.pdf";
            var result = await browser.PrintToPdfAsync(path);
            Debug.Assert(result);
        }
    }
}
```

There's an example of using a SynchronizationContext included in the [official example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.OffScreen/Program.cs#L48).